# linkFn in angular directives is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
var $directive = angular.module('myApp', []);
    $directive.directive('chandanSingh', function(){
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
         compile:function(element, attrs){
               console.log('This is complie');
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              console.log('This is link');
         },
         template: '<h4>{{title}}</h4>',
         controller:function($scope){
               $scope.title = "My Directive";
         }
    };
});

<chandan-singh></chandan-singh>
```

Above is my angular code for directive and HTML directive. i am trying to use "link: linkFn" of directives while using compile in it. Is it even possible to use both compile and link for same directive?

Can anyone help me out with this? what is it i am missing to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a compile function, it must return the link function. Otherwise it won't work:

```
     compile:function(element, attrs){
           console.log('This is complie');

           return function link(scope, element, attrs){
                console.log('This is link');
           },
     },
```

Comment: Hey @Narretz what will be the scope of scope variable in link function? i mean i was changing the scope variable title which i declared in controller on click of the element but its not showing any changes..? 
       compile: function(element, attrs){
            console.log('this is compile');
            return function link(scope, element, attrs){
                element.on('click', function(){
                    scope.title = 'My Directive 2 on click';
                });
            };
        }

Comment: If you use plain jquery / javascript event handlers, you have to tell angular that a change happened on the scope: scope.$apply(scope.title = '...')